# How to get the id of it...SQLite SimplecursorAdapter?

Tags: android, sqlite, simplecursoradapter

I tried but could not get it...
I tried adding like this

```
new String[] {"name", "_id"}, // I want the value of _id
new int[] {R.id.textView1, id});
```

But still dint work

```
public class Veg extends SherlockActivity implements OnItemClickListener {

private Cursor data;
private DBManager db;
ListView lv;
int id;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.nonveg);
    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list1);
    db = new DBManager(this, null, null, 0);
    data = db.getVeg(); // you would not typically call this on the main thread
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
            R.layout.veg_item,
            data,
            new String[] {"name", "_id"},
            new int[] {R.id.textView1});
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(this);
}
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    data.close();
    db.close();
}
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int i, long l) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //Toast.makeText(this, id, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    //Intent in = new Intent(Veg.this, Veg_View.class);
    //in.putExtra("id", String.valueOf(i)); /// ID need to passed here
    //startActivity(in);
}
```

I need to pass this id to a new activity.
And in new activity i need to retreive corresponding data

Answer (score 0):

This is correct for sending data over to another activity

```
Intent in = new Intent(Veg.this, Veg_View.class);
in.putExtra("id", String.valueOf(i)); /// ID need to passed here
startActivity(in);
```

In your new activity just use this

```
Intent in = getIntent();
Bundle bu = in.getExtras();
int id = in.getInt("id");
```

Comment: It is working but i dont get the value of _id which i'd pull from db

Comment: The value i that you get from the OnItemClick represents the position in the adapter, not the value you pulled from the database that's why you re not getting the correct value in your other activity, you need to get the correct item from the adapter at that position (i) and then get the _id from that object in the adapter

Comment: Parse the cursor into  a list of custom objects (good tutorial: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidSQLite/article.html), create a custom adapter extending BaseAdapter (good tutorial: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html) and then you can inside your onItemClick call 
//mAdapter is you adapter
((YourCustomObject)mAdapter.getItem(i)).getID();

Answer (score 0):

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int i, long l)
```

The last argument is the _id you want
The OnItemClick method signature is
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View view, int position, long id)

`parent` is the adapter

`view` is the root view of the item clicked

`position` is the position on the `Adapter`

`id` the id of the adapter for the item which in the CursorAdapters match the `_id`